# How to get a reverse DNS?

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

all my mails to GMX and WEB come back with the response of spam potential. I'm searching in google and I found, that I need a reverse DNS.

My DNS configuration:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2016110200   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       999.999.999.999
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       999.999.999.999
www                      IN A       999.999.999.999
ftp                      IN CNAME   www
imap                     IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
pop                      IN CNAME   www
relay                    IN CNAME   www
smtp                     IN CNAME   www
@                        IN MX 10   mail
```

What I have to change for a reverse DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to create a ptr record which enables dns to lookup your hostname rather than ip address.

example:

100.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 6230    IN  PTR mailserver.example.com.

Comment: This presumes you have the authority to make a `PTR` record. Some providers will allow this via there control panel, but require the forward name to be correctly set, other will only allow it as a manual process where you need to contact support. If you own a block of addresses (at least a class C) then they might deligate the reverse to your name servers on request.