# PTR record is confusing

Tags: php, dns

I am new in PTR configuration. I dont understand what is going on in this records..

```
$ip_initial = gethostbyname('radio-lolipop.com'); //returns 149.56.132.111
$domain = gethostbyaddr($ip_initial); //returns 111.ip-149-56-132.net
$ip_final = gethostbyname($domain); // returns 149.56.132.111
print_r(dns_get_record($domain)); //in A record it is 149.56.132.111
print_r(dns_get_record('radio-lolipop.com')); //in A record it is 149.56.132.111
```

I found [matched result here](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3A158.69.197.81)

I found [unmatched result here](http://dnsgoodies.com/)

here is DNS entry lookup found in dnsgoodies.com

[image: here is DNS entry lookup found in dnsgoodies.com]

here is reverse lookup found in dnsgoodies.com. "Authoritative answers can be found from:" is null
[image: here is reverse lookup found in dnsgoodies.com]

I am totally confused with those results.

Questions:

1. Is my PTR correct? If not how i will correct it?
2. What is the correct code to check PTR record of my domain in php?
3. Is my reverse DNS accessible by all mail client? how they are handling this?

Comment: Only question 2 is about programming and would be on topic here, the two others are about networking and servers. In any case PTR records are something you handle with your network provider so they are delegated properly, they aren't as simple as forward records.

Comment: thanks for clarification or to point out problems in the post. can you please help me with Question No 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check PTR record of your domain because domains/hostnames do not have PTR records, only IP addresses do.

You can check for PTR record of IP address 149.56.132.111 (but that is not 'your' IP address, IP address belongs to a network provider, in this particular case it is [Canada Montreal Ovh Hosting Inc.](http://whois.domaintools.com/149.56.132.11))

Reverse DNS lookups for IPv4 addresses use the special domain `in-addr.arpa`. In this domain, an IPv4 address is represented as a concatenated sequence of four decimal numbers, separated by dots, to which is appended the second level domain suffix `.in-addr.arpa`. You can find authoritative Name servers for this IP address:

```
[centos@ip-172-31-24-14 ~]$ dig NS  132.56.149.in-addr.arpa. @8.8.4.4

;; ANSWER SECTION:
132.56.149.in-addr.arpa. 86399  IN      NS      dns10.ovh.ca.
132.56.149.in-addr.arpa. 86399  IN      NS      ns10.ovh.ca.
```

You can query Authoritative name Server directly (or any other name server) to get the PTR record value:

```
[centos@ip-172-31-24-14 ~]$ dig PTR 111.132.56.149.in-addr.arpa. @ns10.ovh.ca

;; ANSWER SECTION:
111.132.56.149.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR     111.ip-149-56-132.net.
```

Comment: I understand your point. OVH has a option to change PTR. I need to know the steps of changing PTR. I know for this google can help a  lot but I don't want to try it I just want to do as my clients are there. Thanks

Comment: Usually network providers WILL make custom PTR changes at client's requests, but of course only if the client is only user at this address (and sometimes longer term contract is required) .

Comment: I am the only user of this ip. and my hosting provider have a protocol to let there user to change PTR. i even don't know whether mt PTR is correct  or not. i got different result in different site that i have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your PTR records are not correct. You need to add a new PTR record to your DNS settings. But before that you need to make sure that your Hosting Provider supports PTR records. See [PTR Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) for more information
2. The correct code for checking PTR records from Php is: `dns_get_record("ip address", DNS_PTR);` . See the documentation for [dns_get_record](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) for more information. You can use the [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) function to get reverse dns information for a host.
3. Email servers will not reliably deliver email if the a correct PTR record does not exist. The ip address that your domain name resolves to must resolve back to the domain name.

Comment: Thanks for answer. `print_r(dns_get_record("111.132.56.149.in-addr.arpa", DNS_PTR));` returns `[target] => 111.ip-149-56-132.net` and `print_r(dns_get_record('111.ip-149-56-132.net'));` returns `[type] => A
            [ip] => 149.56.132.111`. can you please tell me what it should be form my domanin radio-lolipop.com DNS record for this domain is ns(1|2).radio-lolipop.com

Comment: I checked your domain radio-lolipop.com using the website: https://mxtoolbox.com/. It shows that your email server is set up correctly. The PTR records are correctly configured. You can test your Email server and DNS records by going to this website: https://mxtoolbox.com/ and then selecting "Test Email Server" from the dropdown. In the text box enter "radio-lolipop.com"

Comment: yes i mentioned it in question in `I found matched result here` and here i get confused when dnsgoodies.com can not varify.

Comment: according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44899886/4574272 I need to add ptr record in my domain dns zone. but unfortunately in cpanel i didn't get the option in Advance DNS zone.

Comment: You should ask your hosting provider to setup the reverse dns and ptr records